# Django - get table data from templates into views.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a restaurant application and currently working on takeaway food functionality i.e. user orders food online.

I am displaying food items from my postgresql database onto my takeaway.html template and assigning each food item a class. Each food item will have an 'add to basket' button, JavaScript provides all functionality related to the basket.

I have found some resources that mention using the GET method with a form but I'm still not too sure. I am curious as to how I can access this 'basket' in my views.py and be able to put the values into my database.

I wish to access the food name, quantity and the price from the table if possible. Any resources or help would be greatly appreciated.

**takeaway.html**

```
      <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
        <h3>Starters</h3>

        {% for starter in starters %}
            <div id="{{ starter.id }}">
            <span class="food-item-name">{{ starter.name }}</span>
            <div class="food-item-details">
                <p>{{ starter.description }}</p>
                <p class="food-item-price">{{ starter.price }}</p>
                <p>{% for a in starter.allergen.all %}{{ a.name }} | {% endfor %}</p>
                <button class="add-item-button" onclick="addToBasket(this)">Add to Basket</button>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>Mains</h3>
            {% for m in mains %}
                <div id="{{ m.id }}">
                <span class="food-item-name">{{ m.name }}</span>
                <div class="food-item-details">
                    <p>{{ m.description }}</p>
                    <p class="food-item-price">{{ m.price }}</p>
                    <p>{% for a in m.allergen.all %}{{ a.name }} | {% endfor %}</p>
                    <button class="add-item-button" onclick="addToBasket(this)">Add to Basket</button>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Basket</h3>

    <form method="get">
        <table id="basket" style="border: 1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total Price of Item(s)</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3 id="basket-total-price">0.0</h3>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

**takeaway.js**

```
    function addToBasket(selected)
    {
    const id = selected.parentElement.parentElement;
    const itemName = id.getElementsByClassName("food-item-name")[0].innerText;
    const itemPrice = id.getElementsByClassName("food-item-price")[0].innerText;

    // check if item already in basket
    if (check(itemName))
    {
        updateQuantity(itemName);
        updateItemPrice(itemName);
    }

    else
    {
        const basketTable = document.getElementById("basket");
        const rowCount = basketTable.rows.length;
        const row = basketTable.insertRow(rowCount);
        const basketRowName = row.insertCell(0);
        const basketRowQuantity = row.insertCell(1);
        const basketRowPrice = row.insertCell(2)
        const basketRowTotalPrice = row.insertCell(3);

        basketRowName.className = "basket-item-name";
        basketRowQuantity.className = "basket-item-quantity";
        basketRowPrice.className = "basket-item-price";
        basketRowTotalPrice.className = "basket-item-total-price";

        basketRowName.innerText = itemName;
        basketRowPrice.innerText = itemPrice;
        basketRowQuantity.innerText = "1";

        updateItemPrice(itemName);
    }
}

        // check if item already in basket
function check(itemName)
{
    const basketTable = document.getElementById("basket");

    for(let i = 0; i < basketTable.rows.length; i++)
    {
        if (basketTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === itemName)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

// update quantity field for item
function updateQuantity(itemName)
{
    const basketTable = document.getElementById("basket");

    for(let i = 0; i < basketTable.rows.length; i++)
    {
        if (basketTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === itemName){
            const itemQuantity = basketTable.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("basket-item-quantity")[0];
            let quantity = Number(itemQuantity.innerText);
            quantity += 1;
            itemQuantity.innerText = quantity;
        }
    }
}

// update price for item and total basket
function updateItemPrice(itemName)
{
    const basketTable = document.getElementById("basket");
    let itemTotal = 0;
    let basketTotal = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < basketTable.rows.length; i++)
    {
        if (basketTable.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML === itemName)
        {
            let itemPrice = basketTable.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("basket-item-price")[0];
            let itemQuantity = basketTable.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("basket-item-quantity")[0];
            let itemPriceTotal = basketTable.rows[i].getElementsByClassName("basket-item-total-price")[0];
            let overall = document.getElementById("basket-total-price");
            let current_price = parseFloat(overall.innerText);

            // update price for items x quantity
            itemTotal = parseFloat(itemPrice.innerText) * parseInt(itemQuantity.innerText);
            itemPriceTotal.innerText = ""+ itemTotal;

            // update basket total price
            basketTotal = current_price + itemTotal;
            overall.innerHTML = ""+basketTotal
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try putting your basket items into either cookies or localstore and when user finally reaches the place order, pick basket items from cookie and send to backend or perform any operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have too much experience with those options. I will definitely keep them in mind though. I have found out that I can access elements with unique 'names' so I have assigned unique names as rows are created within my basket table. I am now stuck onw how do I know which unique names the customer has selected.

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/08/shopping-cart-html5-web-storage/